# How to build this LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, lambda

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class UserProfile { public int Id; public int? ParentId; public string Name; public string Role; }
```

Each UserProfile is a user or an admin. Each user may be a child of a single admin, whose Id is stored in the user's ParentId. Below is an example:

```
IEnumerable<UserProfile> users = new List<UserProfile>{
        new UserProfile(){Id = 1, ParentId = null,  Name = "Admin1", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 2, ParentId = 1,  Name = "User2", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 3, ParentId = 1,  Name = "User3", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 3, ParentId = null,  Name = "Admin2", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 4, ParentId = 3,  Name = "User4", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 5, ParentId = null,  Name = "User5", Role = "Admin" },
        new UserProfile(){Id = 6, ParentId = 3,  Name = "User6", Role = "Admin" },
    };
```

I need to rearrange this list or create another list, so that it will be in specific order:
All admins and their users:

- **Admin1** (full details)
- User2 (full details)
- User3 (full details)
- User5 (full details)
- **Admin2** (full details)
- User4 (full details)
- User6 (full details)

I tried to separate them first, but I don't know how to merge them in the desired order.

```
var adminsOnly = users.Where(p => p.Role.Equals("Admin")).OrderBy(p => p.Id);
var usersOnly = users.Where(p => p.Role.Equals("User")).OrderBy(p => p.Id);
```

Thanks a lot.

**Note: There can be Users without Admins, and Admins without Users.**

Comment: So you just want to sort them in a single list so that the order is: A1, U2, U3, U5, A2, U4, U6?

Comment: Yes, at the end I need to get a list of same type IEnumerable<UserProfile> that is in that specific order.

Answer (score 3):

```
var users = users.OrderBy(p => p.ParentId ?? p.Id).ThenBy(p => p.Role);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
users.Where(x => x.Role == "User" && x.ParentID == null)
     .Concat(users.Where(x => x.Role == "Admin")
                  .ToDictionary(x => x, 
                                x => users.Where(u => u.ParentId == x.Id));
                  .SelectMany(x => new[] {x.Key}.Concat(x.Value)));
```

This will give you a `IEnumerable<UserProfile>`, with all users listed after their admin, and all users with no admin listed first.

Comment: Good idea, but I need to get 1-dimensional list, like the original: IEnumerable<UserProfile>

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver - Where do you want users without admins to be sorted?  Before the first admin?  Or tacked onto the end so that they look like they belong to the last admin?

Comment: @Sigourney_Weaver - Assuming that you want them listed before the first admin (which is where I'd put them), try my updated code.  If you want them listed last, just swap the order of the outer `.Where()` and the `.Concat()`

Answer (score 0):

In light of the new info in the question, Istern's answer seems best. The only shortcoming I see is that users without admins will be sorted into the list by their Ids, not necessarily at the beginning or the end.

Comment: In this code, Admin and user will be tied in the (ParentId ?? Id), you only need to add a second sort to break ties (I used role for it).

Comment: @Istern: I don't think so, since the user's Id is added to the sorting score at the end. As long as there is no user overflow (1000, here) there will be no ties.

Comment: the point was the 1000 there is used only that you can add the Id to break the tie. If the (Parent ?? Id) part tie the Admin and his users, you only need to untie using a secondary sort.

Comment: UserId, same as ParentId are numerical STRINGS.
I just provided a simplified version, UserID or ParentID can be something like "A001B2354566".